# django-bootstrap3 how to fix the large gap between form field and submit button?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is how my `form` looks:

[image]

As you can the `form` and `Go` button are too far separated, I want it to be right next to the `dropdown menu`. Here is my template code that uses `django-bootstrap3`

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-10">
    <form action="" method="post" role="form" class='form-inline col-sm-8'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
        </label class="sr-only" for="choices">Select to Edit</label>
        </div>
        {% bootstrap_field form.choices show_label=False %}
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            {% bootstrap_icon "star" %} Go
          </button>
     </div>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You'll probably need to reduce the margin and/or padding of one or both of the elements in css.